# using getimagesize() to check width and height in array of external images

Tags: php

I have an array made of external image locations.

```
$theSize = array();
foreach($images as $imageChoices) {
$theSize[] = getimagesize($imageChoices);
```

How do I loop through the array $theSizes and return images with a width > 70 and a width > 60

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will loop through the images and compare width,height...if it is greater than the set valid dimensions, then it will insert it into the array $validImgs.

```
$validImgs = array();
$validWidth = 60;
$validHeight = 70;

foreach($images as $imageChoices){
  list($width, $height) = getimagesize($imageChoices);
  if($width >= $validWidth && $height >= $validHeight){
    $validImgs[] = $imageChoices;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$theSize = array();
foreach($images as $imageChoices) {
   list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($imageChoices);
   if($width > 60 && $height > 70)  $theSize[] = getimagesize($imageChoices);
}
//array contents only images ,(width > 60 and height > 70)
print_r($theSize);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a crude mockup how this can be done:

```
$image_60 = array();
$image_70 = array();

foreach($images as $imageChoices) {
    $data = getimagesize($imageChoices);
    if ($data[0] > 60) $image_60[] = $imageChoices;
    if ($data[0] > 70) $image_70[] = $imageChoices;  
}
```

Note that I create two arrays `$image_60` and `$image_70`, one for images with the width > 60 and one for images with the width > 70. What to do there depends on what you want to archive with those images.